# Adding a PHP web reference in a .NET application

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, web-services

I am attempting to add and call a PHP Web Service from my .Net web application.
I try adding the reference like in [this](http://sanity-free.org/article25.html) tutorial but receive this error.

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
```

I see the methods to call into. I ran svcutil and it returned some metadata and the same error. I also tried wsdl.exe and got that same error. I am having trouble understanding whats the best way to go forward.
I have read a lot of SO posts and articles but and now am feeling a little confused.
Any help would be great thanks

EDIT:
This is the xml generated from the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"

    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    xmlns:tns="http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" targetNamespace="http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php">

    <types>

        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php">

            <s:element name="fetchImport">

                <s:complexType>

                    <s:sequence>

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="accessKey" type="s:string" />

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="requestURL" type="s:string" />

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="requestFunction" type="s:string" />

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="requestType" type="s:string" />

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="s:string" />

                    </s:sequence>

                </s:complexType>

            </s:element>

            <s:element name="fetchImportResponse">

                <s:complexType>

                    <s:sequence>

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="fetchImport" type="s:string" />

                    </s:sequence>

                </s:complexType>

            </s:element>

            <s:element name="getLoads">

                <s:complexType>

                    <s:sequence>

                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="accessKey" type="s:string" />

                    </s:sequence>

                </s:complexType>

            </s:element>

            <s:element name="getLoadsResponse">

                <s:complexType>

                    <s:sequence>

                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="getLoads" type="s:string" />

                    </s:sequence>

                </s:complexType>

            </s:element>

        </s:schema>

    </types>

    <message name="fetchImportSoapIn">

        <part name="parameters" element="tns:fetchImport" />

    </message>

    <message name="fetchImportSoapOut">

        <part name="parameters" element="tns:fetchImportResponse" />

    </message>

    <message name="getLoadsSoapIn">

        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLoads" />

    </message>

    <message name="getLoadsSoapOut">

        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLoadsResponse" />

    </message>

    <portType name="ITSDispatchServiceSoap">

        <operation name="fetchImport">

            <input message="tns:fetchImportSoapIn" />

            <output message="tns:fetchImportSoapOut" />

        </operation>

        <operation name="getLoads">

            <input message="tns:getLoadsSoapIn" />

            <output message="tns:getLoadsSoapOut" />

        </operation>

    </portType>

    <binding name="ITSDispatchServiceSoap" type="tns:ITSDispatchServiceSoap">

        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />

        <operation name="fetchImport">

            <soap:operation soapAction="http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php/fetchImport" style="document" />

            <input>

                <soap:body use="literal" />

            </input>

            <output>

                <soap:body use="literal" />

            </output>

        </operation>

        <operation name="getLoads">

            <soap:operation soapAction="http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php/getLoads" style="document" />

            <input>

                <soap:body use="literal" />

            </input>

            <output>

                <soap:body use="literal" />

            </output>

        </operation>

    </binding>

    <service name="ITSDispatchService">

        <port name="ITSDispatchServiceSoap" binding="tns:ITSDispatchServiceSoap">

            <soap:address location="http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php" />

        </port>

    </service>

</definitions>
```

Comment: Does the web service in question expose a WSDL for you?

Comment: @plenderj Not in the way a wcf service does. It looks like it is just a php page with 4 text boxes. And it should expose a wsdl

Comment: @plenderj I tried to download the wsdl save it and run wdsl.exe from  vs cmd prompt and output to a vb file it gave me an error. Error in XML doc <html xmlns=""> was not expected.

Comment: You say you tried to download the wsdl - do you actually have a link to a WSDL for it? If you view it in a web browser you should see XML etc?

Comment: @plenderj i had to view source to see the xml.

Comment: And it was a XSDL, not just xhtml? Do you have a link you could share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the wsdl you posted, on the "its-dispatch.com" site their headers are setup wrong (they are saying they are text/html rather than text/xml).

You have a couple of options, the easiest would be save the text you pasted above to disk somewhere as a text file.  Then import it with the Web Reference importer (you can find that by going to "Add Service Reference", clicking Advanced and selecting "Add Web Reference" and using the file:// protocol to point to your text file.

[image: Service Reference Settings]

[image: Add A Web Reference]

For example I tried it with: **"file:///C:/Users/Kris/Desktop/test.wsdl"** and got a web reference that works.  Then go to the Web Reference in your project and change the "Web Reference URL" from  "file:///C:/Users/Kris/Desktop/test.wsdl" to "http://leopard-ext.its-dispatch.com/ws/request.php?wsdl" and everything should work for you.

[image]

I used the default names that Visual Studio gave to the Web Service, I would recommend changing them to fit in with your naming conventions.

You can find the example project I created here: http://wikisend.com/download/299780/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip

Comment: It responded with html document doesn't contain web service discovery information.

Comment: No it responded with an XML document (the four boxes you see) that has the wrong content-type specified by the web server (well actually it is the default type PHP returns).   You already have the WSDL (you pasted it in your question), save it to a file and load it as shown in my answer.  See the project I created if you are really having problems, I linked it at the bottom of my answer.